# Alert content of input box on click of button -- React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-binding, components

I am making a simple program in React to alert the content of input box on the click of a button. I cannot do that. Can someone help me out please? I am from Angular background!

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {

      this.state = {
       text1: "hello"
      }

    return (
    <div>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.text1}/>
        <button onClick={alpha}>Click</button>
    </div>
   )

   alpha(){
    alert(this.state.text1);
   }

  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues with your code. The state and alpha function should not be inside render, and you'll need to initialize your state and bind the alpha function in the constructor to access them from the rest of your class. The following refactored code should work for you:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
          text1: "hello"
      };

      this.alpha = this.alpha.bind(this);
  }

  alpha() {
    alert(this.state.text1);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.text1} />
        <button onClick={this.alpha}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: still getting error bro. U can check making these changes.

Comment: Sorry, the syntax I used requires a specific babel plugin or bootstrapping the project with create-react-app. I've updated the code & description so it should work for you now.